# REST url @RequestParam encoding cannot be decoded to proper format (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding, character-encoding

I'm writing a Rest controller with Spring MVC, currently I have just one endpoint with one parameter requesting:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/city", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> getCities(@RequestParam String name)  {
    ...
}
```

I'm working with Hungarian city names which can have some special characters (á,é,ő,ű,ú...) - they all come from the database.

When I call the rest endpoint with this:

```
/serviceoffer/region/city?name=Borsod-Aba%C3%BAj-Zempl%C3%A9n
```

I get this string into the name:

```
Borsod-AbaÃºj-ZemplÃ©n
```

but I should get this:

```
Borsod-Abaúj-Zemplén
```

I don't know if it's an encoding/decoding issue, but I tried to decode it without any success.

What could be the solution?
Many thanks!

Comment: What servlet container do you use/how do you deploy the application?

Comment: I'm using Apache Tomcat 7, I'm using it with STS. The project is in the early status, so I'm running the app with the easiest way.

Comment: Have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8

Answer (score 0):

I changed my tomcat 7 to tomcat 8 and the problem was solved... strange...

Comment: Tomcat8 URIEncoding defaults to UTF8 - TC7 defaults to ISO8859-1. There's a little more to know: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Answer (score 0):

Since you use **Tomcat <= 7** and **GET** requests, you should change the URIEncoding from the default ISO8859-1 to UTF-8. Change your HTTP connector settings in `config/server.xml`:

```
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```